# Scraping a webpage for link titles and URLs utilizing BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, text, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a webpage of popular articles which I want to scrape for each quoted webpage's hyperlink and the title of the article it's displaying.

The desired output of my script is a CSV file which lists each title and the article content in one line. So if there are 50 articles on this webpage, I want one file with 50 lines and 100 data points.

My problem here is that the article titles and their hyperlinks are contained in an SVG container, which is throwing me off. I've utilized BeautifulSoup for web scraping before but am not sure how to select each article's title and hyperlink. Any and all help is much appreciated.

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import re 

res = requests.get('http://fundersandfounders.com/what-internet-thinks-based-on-media/') 
res.raise_for_status() 
playFile = open('top_articles.html', 'wb') 
for chunk in res.iter_content(100000): 
    playFile.write(chunk) 
    f = open('top_articles.html') 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'html.parser') 
    links = soup.select('p') #i know this is where i'm messing up, but i'm not sure which selector to actually utilize so I'm using the paragraph selector as a place-holder
    print(links)
```

I am aware that this is in effect a two step project: the current version of my script doesn't iterate through the list of all the hyperlinks whose actual content I'm going to be scraping. That's a second step which I can execute easily on my own, however if anyone would like to write that bit too, kudos to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it in two steps:

- parse the HTML and extract the link to the `svg`
- download `svg` page, parse it with `BeautifulSoup` and extract the "bubbles"

Implementation:

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin  # Python3

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


base_url = 'http://fundersandfounders.com/what-internet-thinks-based-on-media/'

with requests.Session() as session:
    # extract the link to svg
    res = session.get(base_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')
    svg = soup.select_one("object.svg-content")
    svg_link = urljoin(base_url, svg["data"])

    # download and parse svg
    res = session.get(svg_link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')
    for article in soup.select("#bubbles .bgroup"):
        title, resource = [item.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ") for item in article.select("a text")]
        print("Title: '%s'; Resource: '%s'." % (title, resource))
```

Prints article titles and resources:

```
Title: 'CNET'; Resource: 'Android Apps That Extend Battery Life'.
Title: '5-Years-Old Shoots Sister'; Resource: 'CNN'.
Title: 'Samsung Galaxy Note II'; Resource: 'Engaget'.
...
Title: 'Predicting If a Couple Stays Together'; Resource: 'The Atlantic Magazine'.
Title: 'Why Doctors Die Differently'; Resource: 'The Wall Street Journal'.
Title: 'The Ideal Nap Length'; Resource: 'Lifehacker'.
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Which module do I install (for Python3) to utilize urllib.parse and urljoin? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @Harelephant `urllib` is built-in, no need to install it.