# Scraping svg Content from a webpage

Tags: python, svg, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape pdf files of Safety Data Sheets from this link: https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/PK/en/search/2127-03-9?focus=products&page=1&perpage=30&sort=relevance&term=2127-03-9&type=cas_number

The pdf link seems to be part of the SVG content on the webpage. I found [Scraping a webpage for link titles and URLs utilizing BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41556848/scraping-a-webpage-for-link-titles-and-urls-utilizing-beautifulsoup) link and am trying to use the answer to get SVG content.

However, the code does not seem to extract SVG content.

```
base_url = 'https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/PK/en/search/2127-03-9?focus=products&page=1&perpage=30&sort=relevance&term=2127-03-9&type=cas_number'
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 12871.102.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.141 Safari/537.36"}

with requests.Session() as session:
    # extract the link to svg
    res = session.get(base_url, headers = headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')
    svg = soup.select_one("object.svg-content")
    svg_link = urljoin(base_url, svg["data"])
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7MIw.png)

Comment: There is no class `svg-content` in the response, please double check the url

Comment: or if the data is generated dynamically use selenium

Comment: Let me know if you need a selenium solution

Comment: Can you provide a selenium solution?

Comment: Can you post the element as that you want to scrape

Comment: Basically, on the link, you can see four chemicals with an icon to open their Safety Data Sheets (SDS), which I want to scrape. I can open each SDS and use their link to scrape. But I want the code to find the embedded pdf links and then scrape them. I want to automate the process of opening each SDS as well.

Comment: Hi @DanishRajani, so all you need is to download those 4 pdfs using selenium, right?

Comment: Yes, that is the aim.

Comment: So if I give you the code, that clicks on 4 pdf download button, would that do? @DanishRajani

Comment: Yes, I am trying to write the code using selenium, but somehow it's not working. I am unable to locate the SVG icon and click it. I am trying to locate SVG using XPATH but somehow not working. Actually, the larger is to input the CAS number of different chemicals and scrap all SDS pdf files as for each CAS number, there are multiple. First, I am trying to solve the problem of scraping pdfs, then I will work on how to automate the whole process.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a SVG. I clicked and it brought a pdf. Could you try to download by a link, as https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/BR/pt/sds/sigma/d5767 e.g.?

Also, an alternative which doesn't require BS: Selenium. It's quite simple to achieve the desired effect with this tool.
Doc:

- https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/
- https://www.browserstack.com/guide/download-file-using-selenium-python

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes, this is one of the pdfs, but there are four chemicals; hence I was wondering if there is a way to scrap all four pdfs from the link above.

Comment: There is a way: you just need to get those links by using selenium, to click and watch over the page opened.